# Number of zeros of a real polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Let $p(x)=x^{10}+a_1 x^9 +...+a_10$ be a polynomial with real coefficients. If $p(0)=-1,p(1)=1,p(2)=-1$ let $n$ be the number of real zeros of $p(x)$ then -

1. 4 $\leq$ n
2. n=3
3. n=2
4. n=1

Option 2 and 4 are wrong as even degree real polynomial cannot have odd number of real roots (because complex roots are always in conjugates). (Correct me if I'm wrong)

I'm confused in option 1 and 4.
By Descartes Rule of signs $n$ can be 2. I cannot discard the option 1 as I don't know the polynomial and so I don't know if it is increasing/decreasing on the left side of 0 or on the right side of 2.

Comment: $f(x)=x^2$ is of degree $2$ but has one only root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be at least $1$ zero in each of $x\in(0,1)$ and $x\in(1, 2)$ by the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Because the coefficient of $x^{10}$ is positive, $p(x)\to \infty$ as $n\to\pm\infty$. Then, by the Intermediate Value Theorem, there is a zero in $x\in(-\infty, 0)$. Similarly, there must be a zero in $x\in(2,\infty)$.

Thus, there must be at least $4$ zeros, so the correct answer is $\boxed{(1)\ 4\leq n.}$